# replace each char in a string with multi char

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to replace value "123" to JANFEBMAR.
Something like this:
1 replaced to JAN, 2 replaced to FEB ...etc.

I wrote like this 
`select replace(replace(replace(replace('1234','1','JAN'),'2','FEB'),'3','MAR'),'4','APR') from dual;` 
This does not look clean and may have performance impact as well.  How do I achieve through REGEXP_REPLACE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `regexp_replace` with `to_date` function containing `MM` and `to_char` function containing `MON` as the second argument :

```
with t(nr) as
(
 select '1234' from dual
), t2 as
(
select regexp_replace(
                      regexp_replace(nr,(substr(nr,level,1)),
                                     to_char(to_date(substr(nr,level,1),'MM'),'MON')), 
                                  '[^[:alpha:]]', '') str,
       level as lvl                          
  from t
 connect by level <= length(nr) 
)
select listagg(str) within group (order by lvl) as "String"
  from t2;

String
------------
JANFEBMARAPR
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=969ee8e31044082c32f5825bfc5efca3)</kbd>

Btw,you can convert your literal '123'  to whatever you want such as '234', '342', '4587' and test within the demo. 
*The method works as long as you need months between **January(1)** and **September(9)** as in the current case*.

Comment: This won't handle 2-digit months (`OCT` - `DEC`) as its only looking at single digits and will raise an exception if input contains a zero.

Comment: yes, you're right I have to think later, thanks @MT0

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '159' from dual),
  3  mon as
  4    (select to_char(to_date(lpad(regexp_substr(col, '\d', 1, level), 2, '0'), 'mm'), 'mon') val,
  5            level lvl
  6     from test
  7     connect by level <= length(col)
  8    )
  9  select listagg(val, '') within group (order by lvl) result
 10  from mon;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
janmaysep

SQL>
```

Though, your question is somewhat *strange*; what would you want `1312` to be converted to? Is it `janmarjanfeb` or `janmardec`?

Comment: This won't handle 2-digit months (`OCT` - `DEC`) as its only looking at single digits and will raise an exception if input contains a zero.

Comment: ... as my last sentence suggest, @MT0.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to split the string and then convert it to a month name is problematic for several reasons:

1. Say you have a value of `1212`. There is no way of knowing whether this corresponds to `DecDec`, `JanFebDec`, `DecJanFeb`, or `JanFebJanFeb`.
2. You have variable lengths of your strings, since some months are 2-digit and some are 1-digit.
3. Attempting to rip apart and convert a column of strings (or integers representing string values) is inherently poor data management. It's prone to breakage, errors, and expensive inefficient querying. Try literally every other solution before you resort to it.

First thing to ask yourself: ***How does this data get loaded into the table in the first place?***

Somehow you are locating the integer representation of a month and then concatenating it with other months. Why not cast it as a month name instead of an integer before it makes it to this table?

Second question to ask yourself: ***What is the next step for this data?***

A series of strings like "JanFebMar" and "MarFebSep" are not particularly flexible, readable, or useful for much. Most likely you'll have to convert or split these strings later on in your workflow to make them useful.

I would strongly recommend restructuring the table like so:

```
Columns_with_your_other_data | MONTH1 | MONTH2 | MONTH3
```

This allows you to keep the months organized and distinct, cast them as integers or strings, concatenate them or split them, sort them, filter them, whatever you want, all while avoiding errors and extra pressure on the database. Way more flexible! Way less prone to errors. Way more readable. Way better way to manage your data.

If you absolutely cannot under any circumstances restructure the table (which seems unlikely), at minimum you'll need to reformat your integer month values to be two digits instead of one digit (i.e. Jan = 01, not 1), to avoid parsing the wrong month.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
  SELECT '1234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1212' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '123456789101112' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '1 23456789101112' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12AA34' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

The most efficient solution is going to be nested `REPLACE` statements and, unless you have a large number of replacement terms it is going to be the simplest to review (if you format the code neatly):

```sql
SELECT value,
       REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(
                   REPLACE(
                     REPLACE(
                       REPLACE(
                         REPLACE(
                           REPLACE(
                             REPLACE(
                               value, '12', 'DEC'
                             ),
                             '11', 'NOV'
                           ),
                           '10', 'OCT'
                         ),
                         '9', 'SEP'
                       ),
                       '8', 'AUG'
                     ),
                     '7', 'JUL'
                   ),
                   '6', 'JUN'
                 ),
                 '5', 'MAY'
               ),
               '4', 'APR'
             ),
             '3', 'MAR'
           ),
           '2', 'FEB'
         ),
         '1', 'JAN'
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   test_data;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> VALUE            | REPLACED_VALUE                       
> :--------------- | :------------------------------------
> 1234             | DECMARAPR                            
> 1212             | DECDEC                               
> 123456789101112  | DECMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC    
> 1 23456789101112 | JAN FEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC
> 12AA34           | DECAAMARAPR
> ```

**Query 2**:

If you want to iterate over the values then you could build a recursive query (and even handle non-numeric replacements):

```sql
WITH replacements ( item, replacement ) AS (
  SELECT  '1', 'JAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '2', 'FEB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '3', 'MAR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '4', 'APR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '5', 'MAY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '6', 'JUN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '7', 'JUL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '8', 'AUG' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '9', 'SEP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '10', 'OCT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '11', 'NOV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '12', 'DEC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AA', '???' FROM DUAL
),
list ( item, replacement, next_item, max_item ) AS (
  SELECT item,
         replacement,
         LAG( item ) OVER ( ORDER BY LENGTH( item ) ASC, item ASC ),
         MAX( item ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY LENGTH( item ), item ASC ) OVER ()
  FROM   replacements
),
replaced_values ( value, item ) AS (
  SELECT REPLACE( value, item, replacement ), next_item
  FROM   test_data
         CROSS JOIN
         list
  WHERE  item = max_item
UNION ALL
  SELECT REPLACE( value, r.item, replacement ), next_item
  FROM   replaced_values r
         INNER JOIN list l
         ON ( r.item = l.item )
  WHERE  r.item IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT value
FROM   replaced_values
WHERE  item IS NULL;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | VALUE                                 |
> | :------------------------------------ |
> | DECMARAPR                             |
> | DECDEC                                |
> | DECMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC     |
> | JAN FEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC |
> | DEC???MARAPR                          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=de9c30021d09ca3f087f8c795b3cb871)*